# How can I copy a function into a buffer in memory?

Tags: memory, buffer, function-pointers

I'm trying to copy a function into a buffer in memory and execute it from there.
I have created a reference to the actual function and copied it into the memory address with `PAGE_EXECUTE_READ` privileges.
For some reason I'm getting an access violation error.

**This is the code:**

```
void function1()
 {

    WinExec("calc.exe", SW_NORMAL);
 }


int main() 
{

    void* mem = VirtualAlloc(nullptr, 4096, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
    CopyMemory(mem, &function1, 4096);
    VirtualProtect(mem, 4096, PAGE_EXECUTE_READ, NULL);
    ((void(*)())mem)();
    return 1;
}
```

**The buffer in mem:**

e9 b1 03 00 00 e9 7c 28 00 00 e9 63 40 00 00 e9 52 2e 00 00 e9 dd 24 00 00 e9 28
41 00 00 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc
cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc

**The error message:**

0xC0000005: Access violation executing  location 0x0000*****

Answer (score 0):

One problem that you are having for sure is that compilers usually generate code that uses relative calls and jumps.

So for example, your buffer in mem starts with the following 5 bytes in hex:

```
e9 b1 03 00 00
```

That 0xe9 is an opcode that says to treat the next 4 bytes as a signed number in little-endian order and to jump to the address formed by adding that signed number to the address of the first byte following the instruction.

By copying the code from the actual function to the buffer you are changing that  relative jump instruction to mean "jump to the address formed by adding 0x3b1 to the address of the end of that 5 byte instruction in the buffer" which resolves to "jump to the address of the buffer + 0x3b6".

The point is that you generally can't just copy a function from one place to another without checking first that you don't have any relative addressing that will break as a result of the copying.  You can disassemble your function (for example by using the "u" command from windbg) to check for such instructions.

Comment: Thanks!!! now the problem is clear. 
So if I understood correctly the only option that I have is to compile my function and then copy the function's bytes into a buffer?
By doing that I won't have a relative jump instruction, but rather the real function.

Comment: You have to look at the compiled function to see which instructions use relative addresses, not just jumps but also calls and even data references that are formed relative to the address of the end of the corresponding instruction.   Those relative addresses will all become invalid if the function is moved.   In some cases, you can fix the relative  addresses in the copy of the instruction, but only if the copy of the function is sufficiently close to the original function that the distance fits in 32 bits.